# How to fix the regex pattern to match the promise syntax?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex to match promise callback from `.then` until `);` closing function.

```
(then\()(?:(?!\1|\\).)*?\);
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MI3gcx/2)

This works fine until I put `);` in the then function section:

```
...
function (result1) {
        alert(result);
...
```

So this regex doesn't enough.

[image: but when I have]

Is there more safer way to match the promise pattern?

like in this picture:

[image]

Comment: I would be curious why you are trying to parse JavaScript.  Can you tell us what you are really trying to accomplish?  This looks very much like an A-B problem.  You may want to back up and start again with the end goal.

Comment: You cannot handle the complexity of JavaScript source code with a simple regex. You can have `/\s*then\s*\(/m` to match the beginning of a call to `then` using literal syntax, but trying to validate what follows is just a non-starter. (And even that will fail with `somePromise[x]()` where `x = "then"`.) Most programming languages are just too complex (and non-regular) for a simple regex, and JavaScript in particular absolutely is. If you need to parse JavaScript, use a JavaScript parser.

Comment: sure. just to replace the syntax from promise to observable.

Comment: Regex can be a useful tool when writing a parser, but it is not a substitute for a parser.

Comment: I just need to do it one time across many files.

Comment: parser that tell me here a promise callback? where?

Comment: If you want a safer way, then I would suggest learning how to use AST parsers,.  There are plenty available, This site shows various ones, https://astexplorer.net/

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
\.then\([\s\S]+?^    \);
```

But be warned that this is specific to the examples you've shown. If all your replacements are formatted the same then this will work; if not then it will fail catastrophically.

https://regex101.com/r/Jotv5r/1

Comment: Really not sure what the downvote is for. OP specified that this is a one-time thing and this answer will work for that purpose.

Comment: @JonSud Hah, thanks. Good luck with your replacements! Also, are you actually using Javascript to perform the replacement or are you doing this in something like Notepad++?

Comment: Maybe `(then\()\n[\s\S]*?\n[^\S\r\n]*\);` will be more close.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not sure, we'd need a larger range of sample inputs and see which one is more robust; hint, I assume yours is.

Comment: @JonSud If you update your question with a larger range of anticipated samples then you might receive more robust regex suggestions. Pro-tip: the screenshots are an eyesore, just work your sample data into the Regex101 link like I did.